# Object Variablenot set error - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following piece of code. I'm getting the following error "Object variable of With block variable not set". I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
Dim ResizeRange1 As Long
Dim ResizeRange2 As Long


Dim CurrentWorkSheet As Worksheet
Set CurrenWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RådatatillTable3")

Dim Table1 As ListObject
Dim Table2 As ListObject

Set Table1 = CurrentWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table10")
Set Table2 = CurrentWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table13")

ResizeRange1 = Worksheets("PivotTable3").Cells(2, "D").Value + 1
ResizeRange2 = Worksheets("PivotTable for Tabell2").Cells(2, "H").Value + 1

Table1.Resize CurrentWorkSheet.Range("A1:E" & ResizeRange1)
Table2.Resize CurrentWorkSheet.Range("J1:M" & ResizeRange2)
```

Comment: Put [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.  /brokenRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a `t` - `Set CurrenWorkSheet`

Comment: Unbelieve.. spent hours trying to figure it out. Thank you